# Cross References

Tags: cross-referencing, chapters, thesis

I am currently writing my thesis, and some chapters have references to other chapters via `\ref{chap-chaptername}`. However, as it takes a while to compile the entire thesis, I would like to be able to compile a single chapter, but when I do this, obviously the cross references are lost (shown as `??`).

I already use `\setcounter{chapter}{n}` to make the chapter number correct, but is there something I can include like `\chaptercounter{n}{chap-chaptername}` to artificially define these references?

Comment: https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-13

Answer (score 3):

That is exactly what the standard latex `\include`  command is designed for. If you use `\includeonly` to just include one chapter, it retains its chapter number and `\ref` to labels in non-included chapters still work.

You should not need `\setcounter{chapter}{...}`